# Get values from different rows as comma seperated. in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below

```
-------------
ID   | NAME | DEFAULT
-------------
1001 | A    | yes
1001 | B    |no
1001 | C    |no
1002 | D    |no
1002 | E    |yes
1002 | F    |no
1003 | C    |yes
1003 | E    |no
1003 | G    |
-------------
```

I want to achieve the below

```
ID   | NAME  | DEFAULT
----------------------
1001 | A,B,C | A
1002 | D,E,F | E
1003 | C,E,G | C
-------------
```

How can I achieve i am very new to plsql.Please help

I have tried this

```
select id,LISTAGG(name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id),CASE default WHEN  yes THEN name END as "default" from table_name
```

Comment: take a look at listagg function - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030  This is not pl/sql, just straight oracle sql.  Pl/sql is a programming language.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have tried that and got the id,name column successfully but failed to get default column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to aggregate strings in NAME column, so [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) is yours.
2. You need to select a single value from NAME column where DEFAULT is 'yes' so select it with case/[decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions049.htm#SQLRF00631) and aggregate with any function.

```
select
  id
  , listagg(name, ',') within group(order by name asc) as name
  , min(decode(lower(default), 'yes', name)) as default
from yourtable
group by id
```